# Pressing right arrow causes up arrow to be set

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I am overriding `ProcessCmdKey` in a control like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if ((keyData & Keys.Up) == Keys.Up)
        MessageBox.Show("Up arrow");
    else if ((keyData & Keys.Right) == Keys.Right)
        MessageBox.Show("Right arrow");

    // it doesn't matter what I return, the glitch happens anyway
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

And when I press the Up arrow key, the message `Up arrow` appears, but it also appears when I press the Right arrow key. Why is this?

Comment: I really don't know, but wouldn't you use `((Keys)keyData) == Keys.Up)`?

Comment: @mazzzzz I do that now (don't know why it works because how can it equal `Keys.Right` but also `(& Keys.Up) == Keys.Up`?) but I'd like it to do something different when the Shift key is pressed and not have to write the condition again in a seperate `if`.

Comment: Not really OT, but just set a breakpoint on your event handler and check it out.

Comment: The idea is that your casting the keyData to a Keys class enum (which just works), and then comparing it to another enum of the keys class (in this case Keys.Up. I'll write it into an answerr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the comment above for a description of the problem.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == ((Keys)(Keys.Shift | Keys.Up)))
        MessageBox.Show("Up arrow");
    else if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        MessageBox.Show("Right arrow");

    // it doesn't matter what I return, the glitch happens anyway
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

You don't even need to cast it, because the argument is passed in as a key.  So you can compare the two enums just like you would two strings or integers.

Comment: But I want the `if` to be entered also if `Shift + Up` is pressed. Also I wasn't casting it I don't think.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is realy simple `Keys.Right` has value 39 and `Keys.Up` has value 38. Your first bit and operation is 38 or 39 & 38 which is always 38, then you're cheking if 38 is equal to 38 which is always true.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I guess I assumed they were all powers of two like they usually are in C++. How should I test it then?

Comment: Exacly like @mazzzzz said if you get some enum value just compare it with value you're expecting. (`if (keyData == Keys.SomeKey)`)

Comment: Like I said, I want the `if` to be entered even if the Shift key is pressed. In that case, the comparison `keyData == Keys.SomeKey` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

indeed the problem is that the (int)key values are not powers of 2. As long as you only want to capture single keystrokes, you can just use (keys == Keys.Up) or whatever.
When you want to catch control or shift keys as well, this is not possible via (keyData == ((Keys)(Keys.Shift | Keys.Up)))
The solution i used is maybe not the most sophisticated, but I can't spoil a lot of time on this kind of items. This approach at least works:

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

if  ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))) // Only act on on keydown
{
  // allkeys will contian something like "LEFT,SHIFT". Carefull in debugger:
  // Tooltip and Watch value still assumes powers of 2 and will show wrong values
  string allkeys = keys.ToString().ToUpper();
  bool shift = allkeys.contains("SHIFT");
  bool alt = allkeys.contains("ALT");
  bool control = allkeys.contains("CONTROL");
  if(allkeys.Contains("UP"))
  {}
  else if(allkeys.Contains("DOWN"))
  {}
  else if(allkeys.Contains("LEFT"))
  {}
  else (allkeys.Contains("RIGHT"))
  {}
}
```